# Html.checkboxfor posting false value to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Close, new { disabled = "disabled" })
```

The above html helper method generates the following html code.

```
   <input checked="checked" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Close field is required." disabled="disabled" id="Close" name="Close" type="checkbox" value="true">

<input name="Close" type="hidden" value="false">
```

When I submit the form it only posts back false... any idea could this be? I checked the post back value in fiddler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disabled controls do not post back. Since `@Html.CheckBoxFor()` generates both a checkbox and a hidden input with the default value (`false`) only the hidden input is posted back and the value of `Close` is false.

Comment: Ah thanks, do you know of any way around making a readonly/disabled checkbox submit back to the controller?

Comment: Since its not editable, use `@Html.hiddenFor(m => m.Close)` so it posts back, and it you want a visual indication of the property as well, add `@DisplayFor(m => m.Close)`

Comment: @DisplayFor(m => m.Close) did the job

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can check false or not false in your Controller:

```
var isChecked = Request.Form["Modelname"];
```